# Implementation of map returning list of lists instead of list

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am trying to implement my own version of Python's map function. I am calling it my_map. The constraint is to use **functional programming** (if statements are permitted, loops are not).

Here's the implementation:

```
# f is the function it takes in, and ls is the list to apply this function over.
def my_map(f, ls):
    if len(ls) != 1:
        ret = my_map(f, ls[1:])
        return [f(ls[0])] + [ret]
    else:
        return f(ls[0])
```

But when I run this with the following input:

```
def f(x):
    return x * x
```

`my_map(f, [1,2,3,4])` returns `[1, [4, [9, 16]]]`

while `map(f, [1,2,3,4])` returns `[1, 4, 9, 16]`, which is what I expect.

Any idea on how I can get my expected results?

Answer (score 3):

```
return [f(ls[0])] + [ret]
```

should be

```
return [f(ls[0])] + ret
```

. You were creating a new, single-element list from `ret`, but only the first one should be a single-element list.

Also, a generator would probably a lot more efficient. You’re making lots of partial lists.

```
def my_map(f, ls):
    it = iter(ls)

    def go():
        yield f(next(it))
        yield from go()

    return list(go())
```

Comment: I get this: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: @periphery: Oh, the last `return f(ls[0])` should be `return [f(ls[0])]`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I also found another way to do it, which I added as an answer too.

Comment: @periphery: That works? `+` and `extend` should do the same thing in this case… and `extend` doesn’t return anything.